# Can I set up a PHP file to act as a handler for a file extension?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cgi

Lets say I have a file with a `.quote` extension. I'd like the web server to send the contents of this file through a simple PHP script before sending it to the browser.

For example:

> This is a quote

Would be transformed to

> "This is a quote"

---

It looks as though I need to put something in my `.htaccess` along the lines of

```
AddHandler x-quote .quote
Action x-quote /cgi/quote.cgi
```

And then my script would be something like

```
#!usr/local/php5
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");

    #I don't know how to do this step...
    echo '"'.$CONTENTS_OF_THE_FILE.'"'; 
?>
```

However, now I just get an error 404 when I look at the `.quote` file on the server. 
I can think of a few things that might be causing this:

1. **The cgi file is not being found and/or executed** - How can I determine if cgi files are allowed to run on my server? Should the path be relative to the webroot?
2. **The path to the php executable is incorrect** - Is this listed somewhere in php.ini? If so, where?
3. **I'm not doing the right thing in the PHP itself** - What should I be doing

I do not have SSH access to the server in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just run it through a normal PHP file rather than CGI and use mod_rewrite?
Your .htaccess would look like

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?).quote$ quote.php?f=$1
```

Your PHP:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$quote = file_get_contents($_GET['f']);
echo '"'.$quote.'"';   

?>
```

Comment: Won't `file_get_contents($_GET['f'])` be rewritten again?

Comment: ofcourse, sanitizing your $_GET variables before using.
@Eric, this is done within a php script. It won't follow url rewrites.